# regex to match or ignore a set of two digit numbers

Tags: python, regex

I am looking for a **regex** in python to match everything before 19 and after 24.

File names are  **test_case_*.py**, where the asterisk is a 1 or 2 digit number.
eg: test_case_1.py, test_case_27.py.

Initially, I thought something like *[1-19]* should work,it turned out to be much harder than I thought.

Has any one worked on a solution for such cases?

PS:i am ok even if we can find a one regex for all numbers before a number x and one for all numbers after a number y.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like

```
"(?<=_)(?!(19|20|21|22|23|24)\.)[0-9]+(?=\.)"

One or more digits `[0-9]+`
that aren't 19-24 `(?!19|20|21|22|23|24)` followed by a . 
following a _ `(?<=_)` and preceding a . `(?=\.)`
```

http://regexr.com?35rbm

Or more compactly

```
"(?<=_)(?!(19|2[0-4])\.)[0-9]+(?=\.)"
```

where the 20-24 range has been compacted.

Comment: @arshajii I like the original answer. It's clear that matching 19-24 is all that is needed for the logic in a program to identify files that are not 19-24. The question did say "to match or ignore a set of numbers" meaning that the author could easily use an answer which matched them.

Comment: Thats great... but i am trying to avoid hard coding. let us consider 19 and 24 as x and y.

Comment: @KiranBangalore sadly in regexes it doesn't work that way :-)

Comment: i am ok even if we can find a one regex for all numbers before x and one for all numbers after y.

Comment: @KiranBangalore Regexes aren't made for math. You can't make a regex that say "any number < x" or another that say "any number > y". What you can do is make a list of all the patterns that are < x, but this list must be built. If I wanted a list of all the numbers < 123, the expression would be `[0-9]|[0-9][0-9]|1[0-1][0-9]|12[0-3]` (compressible to `[0-9]{1,2}|1[0-1][0-9]|12[0-3]`). You can't "generalize" it... You clearly can build a method that builds a regex < x or > y, but it's something different (and quite complex, not something that can be built in 10 minutes)

Comment: @KiranBangalore Now let's take any number > 123... `12[4-9]|1[3-9][0-9]|[2-9][0-9][0-9]|[1-0][0-9]{3,}`

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't use a regex for validating the number itself, I would use one only for extracting the number, e.g.:

```
>>> import re
>>> name = 'test_case_42.py'
>>> num = int(re.match('test_case_(\d+).py', name).group(1))
>>> num
42
```

and then use something like:

```
num < 19 or num > 24
```

to ensure `num` is valid. The reason for this is that it's *much* harder to adapt a regex that does this than it is to adapt something like `num < 19 or num > 24`.

Comment: Very good. Much better to do something a simple way. Simple also lets you adapt it like you said.

Comment: The problem is few test case frameworks use regex to match testcase names. like -match=regex. i am tring to find a soultion for that case

Answer (score 2):

The following should do it (for matching the entire filename):

```
^test_case_([3-9]?\d|1[0-8]|2[5-9])\.py$
```

Explanation:

```
^             # beginning of string anchor
test_case_    # match literal characters 'test_case_' (file prefix)
(             # begin group
  [3-9]?\d      # match 0-9 or 30-99
    |             # OR
  1[0-8]        # match 10-18
    |             # OR
  2[5-9]        # match 25-29
)             # end group
\.py          # match literal characters '.py' (file suffix)
$             # end of string anchor
```

Comment: This is very good practice, defining what you accept rather than what you don't accept, the best secure way of doing regular expressions.